# How to read Roll and Pitch with Turtlebot3?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the Turtlebot3 with ROS2 Foxy and I can't read the Roll and Pitch, just the Yaw. I'm using this launch:
roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch

and the result is:
[image: image description]

Which is the same result presented at the [documentation](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/basic_operation/)

I tested, my opencr itself and it really has the gyroscope to read the 3-axis.

So, what I have to do to have access to the Roll and Pitch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416546/how-to-read-roll-and-pitch-with-turtlebot3?/) by [gabrielc15](https://answers.ros.org/users/154231/gabrielc15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How to read Roll and Pitch

You obtain these from the IMU sensor. The ros driver typically publishes on a topic named something like `/imu/data`. By reading the raw sensor data, you are getting the values in the IMU frame. You may need to apply a transformation if you want the values in some other frame (like world or map.)

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gabrielc15](https://answers.ros.org/users/154231/gabrielc15/) on 2023-06-19**:
Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.
Just to clarify for future users, the topic is named /imu